# sscanf works differently after switching to new compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio, scanf

I have different behavior of scanf function in two different versions of compiler.

```
    int number;
    int offset = 0;
    const char* ref = "123456";
    sscanf(ref, "%d %n", &number, &offset);
```

I don't understand why for Visual Studio 2013 version 12.0 offset == 4 and for Visual Studio 2017 version 15.9 offset == 6. Is it bug of older version?
When I remove space both versions show correct number:

```
    sscanf(ref, "%d%n", &number, &offset);
```

How %d%n is different from %d %n?

Comment: This is just a guess, but you should check the return value of `sscanf`: does it return 2 with both compilers?

Comment: What is the size of `int` on each machine? `std::cout << sizeof(int) << "\n";`

Comment: The "Space" in a format string will read zero or more white space characters. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf

Comment: @MartinYork is `int` allowed to be so narrow that it cannot hold 12345 ?

Comment: @DanielJour The min allowed maximum value of a signed int is `32767`.

Comment: Woops, the return value should be 1 ...

Comment: "why for Visual Studio 2013 version 12.0 offset == 4 " --> its broke.

Comment: user7242858 Suggest you try code again and post the return value from `sscanf()`, which should be 1 - in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How `%d%n` is different from `%d %n`?

The first counts only the characters consumed by `%d`, while the later also counts any possibly following whitespace characters.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>


void test(const char * ref, const char * fmt)
{
    std::cout << "fmt: \"" << fmt << "\"  ref: \"" << ref << "\"" << std::endl;
    int number;
    int offset = 0;
    int ret = std::sscanf(ref, fmt, &number, &offset);
    std::cout << " - Returned: " << ret << "  Offset: " << offset << "  Number: " << number << std::endl;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    test("123456", "%d %n");
    test("123456", "%d%n");
    test("123456  ", "%d %n"); // case 3
    test("123456  ", "%d%n");  // case 4
}
```

([Live on ideone](https://ideone.com/af7lQe)); Output:

> ```
> fmt: "%d %n"  ref: "123456"
>  - Returned: 1  Offset: 6  Number: 123456
> fmt: "%d%n"  ref: "123456"
>  - Returned: 1  Offset: 6  Number: 123456
> fmt: "%d %n"  ref: "123456  "
>  - Returned: 1  Offset: 8  Number: 123456
> fmt: "%d%n"  ref: "123456  "
>  - Returned: 1  Offset: 6  Number: 123456
> ```

Note how in case 3 the 2 appended whitespace characters are counted (so offset = 8) while in case 4 they are not counted (so offset = 6).

---

> I don't understand why for Visual Studio 2013 version 12.0 offset == 4 and for Visual Studio 2017 version 15.9 offset == 6. Is it bug of older version?

This indeed seems like a bug.  Possibilities:

- the `%d %n` is interpreted as requiring whitespace after the number in order for `%n` to "take effect". Your input "123456" has no following whitespace, so it's leaving `offset` undefined.  This violates the standard, because it clearly says that whitespace characters in the format string match **zero or more** whitespace characters in the input string. Exact wording: "A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by reading input up to the first non-white-space character (which remains unread),[..] This directive never fails." ([N1570§7.21.6.2/5](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf))
- the `sizeof(int)` on your older platform is too small to represent the number `123456`.

  > min allowed maximum value of a signed int is `32767` (thanks @MartinYork)

  This would mean that `sscanf` with `%d` can only read `12345` but not `123456`, thus leaving the `6` in the input.  This *should* result in an offset of 5 - not 4 - though!

---

**Solution:** Decide on whether You need semantics of `%d%n` or `%d %n` first, then add a test case to your test suite (you have one, don't you?) to make sure the provided function conforms to your expectations.  Provide a own implementation if needs be.